# Ember-data resolves wrong API endpoint

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

I'm having an issue getting Ember.js with Ember Data to hit a nested resource API endpoint.  Here is my code:

> https://gist.github.com/feliksg/7470254

Here is what i'm using:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:3224
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.2.0-beta.3 ember.js:3224
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.2 ember.js:3224
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.0.0 ember.js:3224
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.0.3 ember.js:3224
DEBUG: -------------------------------

I'm also using Ember Appkit as the base for this project.
```

Basically the issue is when I try to submit a new post, ember data does the following:

> **POST request to /user/posts**

instead of a

> **POST request to /users/1/posts**

In addition, for some reason the request payload as shown by chrome inspector shows the form data being passed to the API looks like this:

> { "user/post": { "published":false, "created_at":null, "user":"1" } }

However, I would expect the data to be passed in like this:

> {"post": { "body":"some text...", "published":false, "created_at":null, "user_id":"1" } }

So for some reason, it doesn't even pass in the 'body' field even though I have it in the form.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

**UPDATE 1**

When I visit `http://localhost:8000/#/users/1/posts`, it sends a GET API request to `/users.json`.  There must be something wrong with the way I set up the PostsRoute but i'm not sure how to fix it.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I've updated my PostsRoute to fetch the JSON without using Ember Data which returns the records, but now the posts template does not render.  My PostsRoute now looks like this:

```
PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    user = @modelFor('user')
    userId = user.get('id')
    return $.getJSON('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/' + userId + '/posts.json')
```

I also get the following error:

> Error while loading route: TypeError: Object # has no method 'slice'

Answer (score 0):

So when you create/use 'users/post' you are defining a namespace where the post lives, not that it's underneath a specific model. AKA, it isn't going to use the associated user model to build up your url, it's just going to make requests using users as part of the post.

I'm not totally positive why the body isn't being attached to the post, are you sure the model includes the body?  Are you sure the body property exists on the model you are sending into the createRecord?

BTW, needs doesn't do anything on a route, it only applies to controllers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but here is the PostsCreate route: https://gist.github.com/feliksg/7470254#file-posts_create_route-js

Comment: Yep, I checked that I have a body attribute on my Post model (https://gist.github.com/feliksg/7470254#file-post-js).  Also, I removed the needs on the route.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific, on `this.get('model')` when you create the record, newPost.createRecord('user/post', this.get('model'));

Comment: So I just tried to submit a new post and did a console.log(this.get('model')); which outputted:                  Class {toString: function, willDestroy: function, _oldWillDestroy: function, created_at: Thu Nov 14 2013 13:57:37 GMT-0500 (EST), constructor: function…}
__ember1384455451199: "ember669"
__ember1384455451199_meta: Meta
_super: undefined
published: true
body: "Test"
created_at: Thu Nov 14 2013 13:57:37 GMT-0500 (EST)
toString: function () { return ret; }
willDestroy: function superWrapper() {
__proto__: Object

Comment: Just for the sake of trying, if you try and change your hasMany and createRecord from 'user/post' to just 'post' what happens?

Comment: I get: Assertion failed: No model was found for 'post'.  If I move the post model out of the user folder, then it finds the model, but then the url ember-data POST request is: /posts instead of /user/1/posts